# view.getWidth not working

Tags: android, bitmap

I have this line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(surface.getWidth(), surface.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

the view:

```
LinearLayout surface = new LinearLayout(this);
surface = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.surface);
surface.addView(gv);
```

when i put random numbers instead of the `surface.getWidth()` `surface.getHeight()` in the `createBitmap`- it works.
i have used `surface.getLeft()` in some other place in the code and it worked.

it makes an error, the logcat:

```
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.snake/com.example.snake.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:687)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:666)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:633)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at com.example.snake.GameView.<init>(GameView.java:42)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at com.example.snake.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-24 16:39:07.999: E/AndroidRuntime(909):  ... 11 more
```

**Edit1:**

mainActivity code:

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
        GameView gv;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.game_view);
            LinearLayout surface = new LinearLayout(this);
            surface = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.surface);
            gv= new GameView(this,surface);
            surface.addView(gv);
    }
```

GameView class:

```
    public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        private boolean isRunning=false;
        private final long FPS=12;
        int PART_SIZE=6;

        private SurfaceHolder holder;
        Thread snakethread;
        Snake snake;
        Arena a;
        Brick food;
        LinearLayout view;
        Bitmap arena;


    public GameView(Context context,LinearLayout view) {
        super(context);
        this.view=view;
        arena = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        this.a=new Arena();
        snakethread=new Thread(this);
        holder= getHolder();
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);                 
        this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
                setRunning(true);
                snakethread.start();

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {



            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

                setRunning(false);

                while(true){
                    try {
                        snakethread.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    });
        snake=new Snake(20, 50, "RIGHT",PART_SIZE);
}

    public void run() {
        long stepPerSecond=1000/FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;
        Canvas c = null;
        try{
            c=this.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (this.getHolder()) {
                ArenaDraw(c);
                }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
        finally{
            if(c!=null){
                this.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
        while(isRunning){
            c=null;
            startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            try{
                c=this.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                synchronized (this.getHolder()) {
                    Paint p=new Paint();
                    snakeDraw(c);
                    }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
            finally{
                if(c!=null){
                    this.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            sleepTime= stepPerSecond-(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
            if(sleepTime>0)
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

i added this:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.game_view);
    LinearLayout surface = new LinearLayout(this);
    surface = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
    surface.setLayoutParams(params);
    gv= new GameView(this,surface);
    surface.addView(gv);
```

I added this in the MainActivity, still same error. what did i do wrong?

**EDIT 3:**

```
        LinearLayout surface = new LinearLayout(this);
    surface = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
    surface.setLayoutParams(params);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_view);
    gv= new GameView(this,surface);
    surface.addView(gv);
```

Comment: why are you making the linear layout instance with "surface" name at runtime?? If you already have a linear layout in xml then use that only.

Comment: does it matter? and how to do it?

Comment: show your MainActivity code !!

Comment: i edited and added the code

Answer (score 0):

The reason this error is occurring is because at the point where view.getWidth() and view.getHeight() are being called, their values resolve to zero because that view has not yet been inflated. To work around this, you will need to inflate this view. So do something like this (will vary according to what you need):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1); 
// 1 here corresponds to the weight to ensure that it is inflated
// Depending on how you want to split that screen, you will want to assign a weight to the other view as well
surface.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Now, the view would have inflated and the values being returned will not be null. Remember to not forget to set the weights as you require.

Comment: It didnt work, maby i didnt add it right. i aded to the main post the code where i added it

Comment: Can you insert the code I mentioned before setContentView() method?

Comment: I tried,gives an error-the code I tried is in the main post in EDIT3

Comment: The line LinearLayout surface = new LinearLayout(this) is trying to create a new linear layout which has not been inflated. Since you already have this in the xml file, you don't need this line. Can you take out the first two lines of Edit 3 and replace them with LinearLayout surface = (LinearLayout)findViewById(surface);

Comment: ohh i tried again edit3, i noticed that the problem is not that, the problem is that i cant put the setContentView() after the LinearLayout surface = new LinearLayout(this) , it has to be before.

Answer (score 0):

When you create instance for `GameView` your `LinearLayout` is not drawn yet. You are trying to get height/width of something not on screen.

Try overriding `onLayout` method and get width/height in this method.

Or you can try that,

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) surface.getLayoutParams();
```

`llParams.width` and `llParams.height` will give you the answer.

P.S. You might have to inflate the layout before getting parameters, I haven't tested this.

Comment: by imageProcessParams.width you mean llParams.width and same for height?